simple ESC/POS printing with Flutter
I want to make a simple 'hello world' printing on paper with Flutter using MobiIoT POS internal printer.
I tried to use a lot of packages including flutter_esc_pos_utils but didn't work and I'm confused.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PrintPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PrintPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<void> _printHelloWorld() async {
    // Print with ESC_POS internal printer function here 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Print Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _printHelloWorld,
          child: Text('Print Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Do you know anything I can do or any recommendations?
The only outcome I want is to print "Hello world" using POS printer.
